# Split String with comma and get the last two values

Tags: java, string

I have field type string that can get two type of values on it:

1. simple field  e.g. **p1**
2. complex fields     **p1/p2/p3/p4**

Now I have 2 questions:

1. how can I identify that the  type is complex **with little effort as possible** since 
   the check is runs in loop?
2. when I got type complex I need to store **the last two properties** for 
   example p3 and P4?

Comment: What did you try? Have you read API documentation?

Comment: I have tried something like String[] prop = strprop.split("/"); but How I got the last two properties with size -1 there is more convenient way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use split operation and check length.

```
String[] prop = strprop.split("/");
if(prop.length > 1){
    String El = prop[prop.length];
    String El0 = prop[prop.length-1];
}
```

Comment: you should use [java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)... And also, `prop[prop.length];` will return a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: I have tried your code String str = "p1\\p2\\p3";


  String[] prop = str.split("\\");

  if (prop.length > 1)
  {
   String El = prop[prop.length];
   String El0 = prop[prop.length - 1];

   System.out.println("test");
  }

Comment: the error in str.split at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: @FedorE: Note that [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) accepts a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

To answer 1) I would use (assuming variable `str` contains your value):

```
str.contains("/"); // If true => complex type
```

For 2):

```
String[] vals = str.split("/");
String lastVal = vals[vals.length-1];
String preLastVal = vals[vals.length-2];
```

Please note that you should check for array length before trying to get the values, otherwise you're likely to get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Array has no length() method.

Comment: HI I have test your code and i got dump in String[] prop = str.split("\\"); the code is :      String str = "p1\\p2\\p3";


  String[] prop = str.split("\\");

  if (prop.length > 1)
  {
   String El = prop[prop.length];
   String El0 = prop[prop.length - 1];

   System.out.println("test");
  }

Comment: the error is at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)